# Editing a variable length list ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, jquery-templates, editorfor

I have a problem with my `EditorFor`. I have the following model

```
  public class AddNewItemViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
   ...

    public List<ItemDetailViewModel> ItemDetails { get; set; }

    public ItemDetailViewModel ItemDetailTemplate { get; set; }
}

public class ItemDetailViewModel
{
    //Item details 
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "BarCodeValidator", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(AddNewItem))]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessageResourceName = "BarCodeLenghtValidator", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(AddNewItem))]
    public string BarCode { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Item details is mapped to `EditorFor` which is working fine my problem is i want to add a new `ItemDetails` to the view by `jquery`. So i used `Jquery Template`

```
<script id="distanceSuggestionTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
@Html.EditorFor(m => Model.ItemDetailTemplate)
</script>
```

And Jquery code to run this

```
$("#addNewItemDetail").click(function () {
    $('#distanceSuggestionTemplate').tmpl({ Index: 1 }).appendTo('#itemTemplate');
});
```

the problem here that i can't map the newly added html to `List<ItemDetailViewModel> ItemDetails` so i can get that new item with the existing one when posting to the controller. Any suggestions on how to solve that issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you apply `EditorFor` to list it will generate something like this:

```
<input id="ItemDetails_0__Barcode" name="ItemDetails[0].Barcode"/>
<input id="ItemDetails_1__Barcode" name="ItemDetails[1].Barcode"/>
...
```

But template that use `@Html.EditorFor(m => Model.ItemDetailTemplate)` is likely to be:

```
<input id="Barcode" name="Barcode"/>
```

So it can't be mapped to your list.

Possible workaround is to use template with proper list index like:.

```
  `<input id="ItemDetails_n__Barcode" name="ItemDetails[n].Barcode"/>`
```

but it seems not to be an elegant solution. Maybe you need to re-consider way of adding items(use jQuery and ajax instead of ASP.NET MVC editors for example)